# Acquiring list of computers used by user in bat file

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to acquire the list of computer names owned by user in a domain from a .bat script?

My code currently gets the current user's computer name but I'd like to lookup any additional devices in active directory.

```
@ECHO OFF
cls
set /p desk="Desk No: "
echo %username%,%computername%,%desk% >> C:\results.csv
echo Success
```

Comment: By owned, do you mean computers they have accounts on?

Comment: Yes - the computers they have accounts on

Comment: You have to search the computer one by one.

Comment: Can the AD admin provide an audit log of what users id's logged onto what computer names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the users currently logged in really isn't all that hard. But, you really only have a few options here since you are trying to find all computers people have logged into.

1. Run an audit report from for AD that would provide the login info for every log in to the domain.This would be the best option as you could get historical information for who logged in on what machine and when.
2. Add the batch script you have in your question to the Windows start up and start logging the information going forward
3. Get a list of all computer names, check each computer one at a time, and save all the user profile names off each computer.

Most of the articles I find seem to indicate a batch only approach would not be effective without additional software being available (like Powershell).